# Posting multiple comments from javascript console in facebook

Tags: javascript, facebook

This is a sort of a game I saw in facebook to make 10 successive comments to a post. can it be done from javascript console?

Comment: It can be done, but you're going to have to look through the fb source code to find what event is called when you hit enter to post a status. Which will be painful. Maybe try Opera's new-fangled event watcher to see if that makes it clearer.

Comment: any light on this? Kind of old, but still interesting. thanks!

Comment: maybe my answer below will help you @GustavoOliveira

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps, I would recommend you to give the Firefox GreaseMonkey a try.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a script to automatically comment on birthday wishes on FB, and I posted a simplified working solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31078447/post-comments-on-facebook-page-via-console).